# Sales order line

Tags: odoo-12

Hello i'm doing a code with python 3.7 and i need to delete in a order of Sale al Products with quantity with 0. I'm stuck, i know that it mus be easy but not for me at these time.
My last update code:

init.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Part of Odoo. See LICENSE file for full copyright and licensing details.

from . import api, fields
from . import models
from . import wizard
from . import report
from . import sale
from . import sale_order
from . import stock_no0
```

---

manifiest.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Part of Odoo. See LICENSE file for full copyright and licensing details.
   {
        'name' : 'Stock_0',
        'version' : '0.1',
        'summary': 'Invoices & Payments',
        'sequence': 15,
        'description': """
    Stock No 0
    ====================      
        """,
        'category': 'Invoicing Management',
        'website': 'http://no_website.com',
        'depends' : ['base_setup', 'product', 'sale', 'analytic', 'portal', 'digest'],
        'data': [
        'views/boton.xml', 
        ],
        'installable': True,
        'application': True,
        'auto_install': False,
    }
```

stock_no0.py

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):

_inherit = 'sale.order'
@api.onchange
def onchange_product_id_check_availability(self):
    for ordr_ln in self.order_line:
        if ordr_ln['qty_available'] < 0:
                warning_mess = {'title': 'Opps! No hay stock',
                                'message': 'No hay suficiente Stock '}  


@api.multi
def action_delete(self):
    for order in self:
        order.order_line.filtered(lambda l: not l.product_uom_qty).unlink()
```

---

The view in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_order_form">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']" position="before">
                <button name="action_delete" type="object" string="Clean" groups="sales_team.group_sale_manager"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

---

And the error is AttributeError: type object 'sale.order' has no attribute 'action_delete'.

These code must be to Odoo 12

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the `NameError: name 'models' is not defined` because you did not import `models`.

You can use [filtered](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#filter) to get lines with quantity equal to `0` and then call `unlink` method on the result (record set).

```py
from odoo import models, api


class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    @api.multi
    def action_delete(self):
        for order in self:
            order.order_line.filtered(lambda l: not l.product_uom_qty).unlink()
```

In this case the button type should be `object` and its name should be the method name.

```xml
<button name="action_delete" type="object" string="Clean"  groups="sales_team.group_sale_manager"/>
```

Comment: I've got these error AttributeError: type object 'sale.order' has no attribute 'action_delete'

Comment: The button `name` should be a method of sale order. In your example above the button name should be `delete_0`.

Comment: Hello Kenly i've do it but i don know where is my mistake.I've published all my code.

Comment: I created a new module based on your code, I tested it and it works, the only difference is that I added the `sale` module to the `depends` entry in the manifest file.

Comment: The same AttributeError: type object 'sale.order' has no attribute 'action_delete'

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 752, in call_kw
    method = getattr(type(model), name)
AttributeError: type object 'sale.order' has no attribute 'action_delete'

Comment: You can find a test module I used to test your code at [Odoo test module](https://pastebin.com/E6AjWj4P)

Comment: Thanks Keny You are great, i've learn a lot with you.